# How to make use of a exploit that is not available in metasploit?

Tags: exploit, vulnerability, iis

I want to exploit a Microsoft IIS HTTPD 10.0 server open which is open in PORT 80. However there is no available exploits in Metasploit but there are few vulnerabilities in [this](https://www.cybersecurity-help.cz/vdb/microsoft/microsoft_iis/10.0/) site. Is it possible to make use of these vulnerabilities?

Comment: Yes,you can exploit it by crafting the exploit.

Comment: If you have the exploit, it can be used, with or without metasploit. Metasploit is just a tool to make using exploits easier.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to make use of these vulnerabilities?

Theoretically yes, As you mentioned the exploit doesn't exist in Metasploit framework, check if exploits exist on exploit-db site or POC for the CVE on GitHub. If the exploit/POC does not exist, study the CVE by figuring out what exactly leads to that weakness mention in CVE  and try to reproduce the vulnerability locally on the server. After you are done reproducing the vulnerability on the local server successfully, try it on the target server.